# use matlab to open a file with an outside program and execute 'save as'

Tags: matlab, file-conversion

Alright, here's what I'm dealing with (you can skip to TLDR if all you need to see is what I want to run):

I'm having an issue with file formatting for a nasty conglomeration of several ancient programs I've strung together. I have some data in `.CSV` format, and I need to put it into `.SPC` format. I've tried a set of proprietary MATLAB programs called 'GS tools' for fast and easy conversion, but fast and easy doesn't look like its gonna happen here since there are discrepancies in how `.spc` files are organized now and how they were organized back when my ancient programs were written.

If I could find the source code for the old programs I could probably alter the GS tools code to write my `.spc` files appropriately, but all I can find are broken links circa 2002 and earlier.  Seeing as I don't know what my programs are looking for, I have no choice but to try resaving my data with other programs until one of them produces something workable.

I found my Cinderella program: if I open the data I have in a program called `Spekwin` and save the file with a `.spc` extension... viola!  Everything else runs on those files.  The problem is that I have hundreds of these files and I'd like to automate the conversion process.

I either need to extract the writing rubric `Spekwin` uses for `.spc` files (I believe that info is stored in a `dll` file within the program, but I'm not sure if that actually makes sense) and use it as a rule to write a file from my input data, or I need a piece of code that will open a file with `Spekwin`, tell `Spekwin` to save that file under the `.spc` extension, and terminate `Spekwin`.

TLDR: Need a command that tells the computer to open a file with a certain program, save that file under a different extension through that program (essentially `open*.csv>save as>*.spc`), then terminate the program.
OR--I need a way to tell MATLAB to write a file according to rules specified by a `.dll`, but I'm not sure I fully understand what that entails.

Of course I'm open to suggestions on other ways to handle this.

Comment: @Nitish when the Spekwin program saves my CSV as an SPC, it does something to the format of the data which I have no easy way of deciphering.  Unfortunately, it's not enough to simply copy the file and change the extension, as my other programs are expecting the specific format output by Spekwin's saving convention.

Comment: This is a non-issue for me now.  While I did not find a way to perform the action I requested help with, I was able to solve the problem in another way.  I'd still be interested in whether or not such a thing as I suggested in my question is possible, but it is less pressing now. Thanks to all.